# Python 2.7 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'username'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm running through a tutorial with Flask and Python, and now setting up a dummy DB with SQLAlchemy and SQLite.

I'm working in the Python terminal interpreter and successfully created a dummy record from my 'User' table class as below:

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20),unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    image_file = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default='default.jpg')
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False,)
```

I then queried 'username' and created a variable from the result. When I use this data, I get an error exactly as below (copied from terminal):

```
>>> user_2 = User(username='Yuki', email='c@d.com', password='pass')
>>> db.session.add(user_2)
User.query.filter_by(username='Yuki').all()
[User('Yuki','c@d.com,'default.jpg')]
>>> Yuki = User.query.filter_by(username='Yuki').all()
>>> Yuki
[User('Yuki','c@d.com,'default.jpg')]
>>> Yuki.username
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'username'
```

As you can see, the data is all there when I query the record, but it won't return the username attribute under this query.

Have I misunderstood the syntax? It clearly registers and stores the username correctly. Please let me know if you can spot anything obvious, I'm hoping it's a simple mistake! Thanks in advance for any suggestions, I'm really enjoying setting this up and would love to continue.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> Yuki = User.query.filter_by(username='Yuki').all()
>>> Yuki
[User('Yuki','c@d.com,'default.jpg')]
```

So `Yuki` is a list with 1 element of type `User`. (It should better be named `yuki`.)

```
>>> Yuki.username
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'username'
```

The error is clear: a list has no username.

But a list has elements, in this case 1 element. `Yuki[0].username` should give you what you want.

Comment: Thank you this stopped the error and returned the username, but also returned the character 'u' : >>> Yuki[0].username
u'Yuki'

Comment: I understand! .all() returns a list, so i have to use [ ]. The tutorial uses .first(), which is why they don't define an array position. Thank you for clearing this up

Comment: @Andyjm It is not a character within the string, but an indication that it is a (unicode) string (under py 2.x).